# Check amount of heap space by running a program; not matching with actual boundaries

Tags: c, memory, malloc, heap-memory

I need to know the amount of heap space allocated for a process. In theory call malloc(1) (in C program) only once will get a start address of heap in my code. And call sbrk(0) a system call which return end of heap space allocated to that process. Below is my test code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef ALLOCATE_BYTES
#define ALLOCATE_BYTES 0x1000000
#endif /* #ifndef ALLOCATE_BYTES */

void subroutine (void);
int main()
{
    void *init_ptr = malloc((size_t) 1);
    void *end_ptr = sbrk((intptr_t) 0);

    printf(" Total Heap space = %lld B = %lld kB  \n", 
    (long long) (init_ptr - end_ptr),
    (long long) (init_ptr - end_ptr)/1024);

    subroutine();

    end_ptr = sbrk((intptr_t) 0); /* New edit 1 */
    printf(" Total Heap space = %lld B = %lld kB  \n", 
    (long long) (init_ptr - end_ptr),
    (long long) (init_ptr - end_ptr)/1024);

    return 0;
}


void subroutine (void)
{
    void *ptr;
    long long count = 0;
    size_t size = ALLOCATE_BYTES;
    size_t size_p = ALLOCATE_BYTES + 1;
    long long mem_alocated = 0;

    printf("  start rate to %u  \n", size);
    while (1)
    {
    ptr = malloc((size_t)size);

    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        mem_alocated += size;
        count++;
    }

    if ((ptr == NULL) && (size == size_p))
    {
        size/=2;
        printf("overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE %*u & "
        "current count = %lld ---> total bytes %lld \n"
        , 7, size, count, mem_alocated);
    }

    if ((ptr == NULL) && (size == 1))
    {
        printf("overflow....!! at %lld for %lld bytes\n", 
        count, count * ALLOCATE_BYTES);
        break;
    }
    size_p = size;
    }
}
```

The following is the results:

```
$ gcc -o exmpl_heap_consume exmpl_heap_consume.c -DALLOCATE_BYTES=0x10000
$ ./exmpl_heap_consume
 Total Heap space = -135160 B = -131 kB  
  start rate to 65536  
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE   32768 & current count = 48792 ---> total bytes 3197632512 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE   16384 & current count = 49084 ---> total bytes 3207200768 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE    8192 & current count = 49371 ---> total bytes 3211902976 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE    4096 & current count = 49658 ---> total bytes 3214254080 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE    2048 & current count = 49945 ---> total bytes 3215429632 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE    1024 & current count = 50233 ---> total bytes 3216019456 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE     512 & current count = 50521 ---> total bytes 3216314368 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE     256 & current count = 50809 ---> total bytes 3216461824 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE     128 & current count = 51098 ---> total bytes 3216535808 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE      64 & current count = 51100 ---> total bytes 3216536064 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE      32 & current count = 51100 ---> total bytes 3216536064 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE      16 & current count = 51387 ---> total bytes 3216545248 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE       8 & current count = 51389 ---> total bytes 3216545280 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE       4 & current count = 51676 ---> total bytes 3216547576 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE       2 & current count = 51676 ---> total bytes 3216547576 
overflow --> reduced Bytes SIZE       1 & current count = 51676 ---> total bytes 3216547576 
overflow....!! at 51676 for 3386638336 bytes
 Total Heap space = -135160 B = -131 kB
```

This result says theoretical I have "135160 bytes" of memory locations for heap. But if I start consuming all of it till the repeated `malloc()` function call returns `NULL`. While doing so I keep track of how many bytes of memory my program has consumed now.

But here the question is my theoretical heap space (135160 bytes) is not matching with my practical counts (3386638336 bytes). Am I missing anything?

### Edit 2:

I added some checks for the pointer return by the `malloc()` call and aggregated it to see the total. I observed the total bytes allocated is just less than the my theoretical heap space. This would suggest two things `malloc()` internally not calling `sbrk()` and secondly it is allocating memory elsewhere. Am I right till this point or anything missing here?

Comment: malloc may well have called sbrk to enlarge the heap.

Comment: @dmuir I have edited my code to check `sbrk((intptr_t) 0);` call after the heap ran out of memory and printing its current address. If the `malloc()` had internally call the `sbrk()` then the subsequent call to `sbrk()` should give the current break. Unfortunately its not happening and I am still verifying other answers.

Comment: "Unfortunately its not happening" in my previous comment, what I mean is the `sbrk()` returns the same pointer, it was returning before heap space ran out. So I am suspecting the `malloc()` would not call `sbrk()` internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've completely misunderstood `brk`/`sbrk`. `sbrk(0)` will tell the location of *current* program break, aka the end of data segment. When malloc runs out of space, it will call `sbrk` with a positive offset that will resize the data segment, thus moving the program break **further**. The [Linux man page for `sbrk`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk) clarifies this:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> brk() and sbrk() change the  location  of  the  program  break,  which
>          defines the end of the process's data segment (i.e., the program break
>          is the first location after the end of  the  uninitialized  data  seg‐
>          ment).  **Increasing the program break has the effect of allocating mem‐
>          ory to the process; decreasing the break deallocates memory.**
>
> brk() sets the end of the data segment to the value specified by addr,
>          when  that  value is reasonable, the system has enough memory, and the
>          process does not exceed its maximum data size (see setrlimit(2)).
>
> **sbrk() increments the program's data space by increment bytes.**  Call‐
>          ing  sbrk()  with  an  increment  of 0 can be used to find the **current**
>          location of the program break.

*(emphasis mine)*

Furthermore usually on modern malloc implementations allocations of sufficient size (say >128kB) are allocated directly with `mmap` outside of the data segment. I'd test if the pointer returned from `malloc(65536)` even were between an address that is in the initialized data segment (do a global `int foo = 42;`, then `&foo` should be before the `.bss`/uninitialized data) and the current program break.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are not remembering is that your `practical count' is the available RAM on your system, which is used for multiple things.  For example, I modified your program to:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef ALLOCATE_BYTES
#define ALLOCATE_BYTES 0x1000000
#endif /* #ifndef ALLOCATE_BYTES */

int main()
{
    void *init_ptr = malloc((size_t) 1);
    void *end_ptr = sbrk((intptr_t) 0);

    printf("\nmalloc returned: 0x%08x\n", (uint64_t)init_ptr);
    printf("sbrk returned: 0x%08x\n", (uint64_t)end_ptr);

    printf(" Total Heap space = %lld B = %lld kB  \n", 
    (long long) (end_ptr - init_ptr),
    (long long) (end_ptr - init_ptr)/1024);

    sleep(300);

    return 0;
 }
```

I compiled the above using gcc (version 4.8.4) on Ubuntu 14.04 as: `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall temp.c -o temp`; then I ran the following commands at the command prompt:

```
******@crossbow:~/junk$ ./temp &
[2] 2069
******@crossbow:~/junk$ 
malloc returned: 0x01cac010
sbrk returned: 0x01ccd000
 Total Heap space = 135152 B = 131 kB  
******@crossbow:ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1681 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 1775 pts/0    00:00:15 emacs
 2069 pts/0    00:00:00 temp
 2070 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
******@crossbow:~/junk$ cat /proc/2069/maps
       00400000-         00401000 r-xp 00000000 fc:02 10616872                   /home/******/junk/temp
       00600000-         00601000 r--p 00000000 fc:02 10616872                   /home/******/junk/temp
       00601000-         00602000 rw-p 00001000 fc:02 10616872                   /home/******/junk/temp
       01cac000-         01ccd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
   7f16a2e44000-     7f16a2fff000 r-xp 00000000 fc:02 70779581                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
   7f16a2fff000-     7f16a31fe000 ---p 001bb000 fc:02 70779581                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
   7f16a31fe000-     7f16a3202000 r--p 001ba000 fc:02 70779581                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
   7f16a3202000-     7f16a3204000 rw-p 001be000 fc:02 70779581                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
   7f16a3204000-     7f16a3209000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f16a3209000-     7f16a322c000 r-xp 00000000 fc:02 70779574                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
   7f16a3407000-     7f16a340a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f16a3428000-     7f16a342b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f16a342b000-     7f16a342c000 r--p 00022000 fc:02 70779574                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
   7f16a342c000-     7f16a342d000 rw-p 00023000 fc:02 70779574                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
   7f16a342d000-     7f16a342e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7ffcee9ab000-     7ffcee9cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
   7ffcee9ef000-     7ffcee9f1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
   7ffcee9f1000-     7ffcee9f3000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vsyscall]
```

Now, from this you can see that currently the heap starts at 0x01cac000 and runs to 0x01ccd000.  Notice, that malloc does not allocate memory starting from the beginning of the heap.

Also, notice, that the heap can grow upwards till it bumps into the area that dynamic libraries are loaded (in this case, this is at 0x7f16a2e44000).

From the memory map listing above, you can also see where the stack is located, if you have any interest in that, as well as where various parts of your program are loaded.  You can determine what those blocks are by using the `readelf` utility, and you can see:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040 0x0001f8 0x0001f8 R E 0x8
  INTERP         0x000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x0008d4 0x0008d4 R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x000248 0x000250 RW  0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x000e28 0x0000000000600e28 0x0000000000600e28 0x0001d0 0x0001d0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254 0x000044 0x000044 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0007a8 0x00000000004007a8 0x00000000004007a8 0x000034 0x000034 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0001f0 0x0001f0 R   0x1
```

From looking at this, we can see that the area in memory from 0x00400000 to 0x00401000 is occupied by the contents of the file described by the second program header.  This segment contains the following program sections: `.interp` `.note.ABI-tag` `.note.gnu.build-id` `.gnu.hash` `.dynsym` `.dynstr` `.gnu.version` `.gnu.version_r` `.rela.dyn` `.rela.plt` `.init` `.plt` `.text` `.fini` `.rodata` `.eh_frame_hdr` `.eh_frame`.  Probably the most important for you would be the `.text` section, which contains your code.  In fact, the programs entry point is located at 0x00400520 (as determined by `readelf -h`).

Looking at the next area in memory from 0x00601000 to 0x00602000 and referring to the above, we can see that this corresponds to the section of the file described by the third program header.  This segment contains the following program sections: `.init_array` `.fini_array` `.jcr` `.dynamic` `.got` `.got.plt` `.data` `.bss`.